# A convex hull of a union of convex sets

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let ${A_1},{A_2},....{A_n}$ be convex sets in a vector space and suppose $x \in \operatorname{co}({A_1} \cup {A_2} \cup \dotsb \cup {A_n})$. Is it true that $x = {t_1}{a_1} + \dotsb + {t_n}{a_n}$ such that 
$$
  \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{t_i} = 1} \;,\;\; {t_i} \ge 0, {a_i} \in A
$$

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

Put

$A=\{x: x = {t_1}{a_1} + \dotsb + {t_n}{a_n},$ such that $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{t_i} = 1} \;,\;\; {t_i} \ge 0,$ and ${a_i} \in A_i$ for each $i\}.$

Then it is easy to check that $A$ is a smallest convex set which contains the union $ {A_1} \cup {A_2} \cup \dotsb \cup {A_n}$, that is $A$ is a convex hull of the union. It have to be checked the following:

- The set $A$ is convex.
- Each $A_i$ is contained in $A$.
- If $B$ is a convex  set and $B\supset {A_1} \cup {A_2} \cup \dotsb \cup {A_n}$ then $B\supset A$.

In fact, the first two conditions already imply that the convex hull of the union $ {A_1} \cup {A_2} \cup \dotsb \cup {A_n}$ is contained in $A$.